# Query on Name binding on mutable/non-mutable type in python

Tags: python

Based on below python code examples, and the diagram,

```
>>> i=2
>>> j=i
>>> i += 2
>>> j
2
```

---

```
>>> s1 = 'abc'
>>> s2 = s1
>>> s1 = 'def'
>>> s2
'abc'
```

---

```
>>> li = ('a', 'b')
>>> lj = li
>>> lj
('a', 'b')
>>> li = ('d', 'e')
>>> lj
('a', 'b')
```

---

```
>>> l1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000]
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l2
['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000]
>>> l1.append('math')
>>> l2
['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000, 'math']
>>> l1 = ['english']
>>> l2
['physics', 'chemistry', 1997, 2000, 'math']
>>>
```

---

```
>>> def square(x):
        return mul(x, x)
>>> f = square
>>> f
<function square at 0x00000000031F9848>
>>> square
<function square at 0x00000000031F9848>
>>> def square(x):
        return x * x
>>> f
<function square at 0x00000000031F9848>
>>> square
<function square at 0x000000000325D148>
```

---

[image: names]

My question is:

Can i say that, There is nothing like reference variable in python? Variable of any type in run time is a `name` but not `reference`, Am i correct?

Comment: Look at here http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

Comment: @user189 not sure why you think that would be any different. Rebinding a name works exactly the same, whether the content is a mutable thing like a list or a non-mutable thing like a string or tuple.

Comment: Assigning a variable to some other object is not going to modify its other references. It simply decrements one reference count of the older object. `a = b = []; b = [1]` will not change `a` in anyway.

Comment: Also: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @hjpotter92 i think what you guys are saying is correct, let me add additional details to this question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.

Note that none of your examples actually involve mutable types. If they did, though, you would see exactly the same thing: *except*, of course, you can additionally mutate the contents of the item.

```
>>> ll = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> lm = ll
>>> lm
['1', '2', '3']
>>> ll.append('4')
>>> ll
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> lm
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> lm = ['5']
>>> lm
['5']
>>> ll
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Note that mutating the contents affects both lists, but rebinding `lm` to a new list has no effect on `ll`.

Comment: sorry i was about to add one

Comment: for your point: `except, of course, you can additionally mutate the contents of the item.`, can u give an example?

Comment: Isn't that what I have done (and now I see that you have too)? Calling `append` adds a value, and that change is visible from both names until one is rebound.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of.  Python doesn't have pass-by-reference, if that's what you're asking.  But Python variables are *all* references to Python objects.  Thus

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
```

makes `a` and `b` point at the same object (in this case, the integer 1, but it could be a more complex object).  You can see this because

```
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```